# Fibrant objects in Bousfield localization of homotopy pullback closure of Nisnevich hypercovers

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories, topos-theory, motivic-homotopy

Let $M$ be a model topos and $S$ a set of morphisms, there exists a set of morphism $\bar{S}$ which is generated by the $S$-local equivalences which is closed under homotopy pullbacks in $M$. Suppose that $M$ is left proper combinatorial, then the Bousfield localisation $M_{\bar{S}}$ is a model topos [Prop.6.2.1.2, HTT, Lurie].

Let $sPre(C)$ be the category of simplicial presheaves of an essentially small category $C$, the fibrant objects of the Bousfield localisation with respect to the set of all hypercovers $S$ are precisely the $S$-local objects, that is, the presheaves of Kan complexes satisfying descent for all hypercovers. Under suitable condition, this localisation is equivalent to the localisation of the set of all bounded hypercovers. And a presheaf satisfies descent for all bounded hypercover is equivalent to that it satisfies Čech descent. Thus the fibrancy condition can be reformulated for Čech descent which is a relatively concrete condition.

In the case of Nisnevich descent, where $C$ is a site whose topology is defined by a complete bounded regular cd structure, the fibrancy condition can be stated for the distinguished square, that is, a simplicial presheaf $F$ is fibrant if and only if $F$ takes values in Kan complexes and it takes every elementary ditinguished square to a homotopy pullback.

Let $\alpha$ be  a Nisnevich distinguished square, 
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
W @>>> Y \\
@VVV @VpVV\\
U @>i>> X
\end{CD}
and let $P(\alpha)\to X$ be the morphism from the pushout of the upper part $U\leftarrow W \rightarrow Y$ to $X$.

**Question**:
Consider the set of morphism $Nis=\{P(\alpha)\to X\}_{\alpha}$ and the localisation $sPre(C)_{\overline{Nis}}$ of $\overline{Nis}$, are the fibrant objects of $sPre(C)_{\overline{Nis}}$ the same as $sPre(C)_{{Nis}}$?

**Further question after edit:** Consider the category $sPre(C)_{\mathbb{A}_1,\overline{Nis}}$ which has a different model category structure than the motivic homotopy category $sPre(C)_{\mathbb{A}_1,{Nis}}$, are the fibrant objects  in $sPre(C)_{\mathbb{A}_1,\overline{Nis}}$ the same as that for $sPre(C)_{\mathbb{A}_1,{Nis}}$?

I slightly modified the question as now the question is not generally about hypercover as I thought. What I'm looking for are the fibrant objects in the model topos $sPre(C)_{\mathbb{A}_1,\overline{Nis}}$. In the comments below, Pavlov mentioned the paper by [Strunk and Raptis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08467.pdf),

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small simplicial category. Then there is a bijective correspondence between Grothendieck topology $\bar{\tau}$ on $Ho(\mathcal{C})$ and homotopy left exact left Bousfield localization of $sPSh^{\Delta}(\mathcal{C})$ which are $t$-complete.

where a $\mathcal{U}$-local model topos $sPSh^{\Delta}(Sm_S)_{\mathcal{U}Nis}$ is given together with its Grothendieck topology arising from Nisnevich topology on the ordinary category $Sm_S$. $sPSh^{\Delta}(\mathcal{C})$ denotes the functor category of simplicial functors $\mathcal{C}^{op}\to \mathcal{sSet}$ for a small simplicial category $\mathcal{C}$. A Grothendieck topology for a simplicial category $\mathcal{C}$ is by definition a Grothendieck topology on $Ho(\mathcal{C})$.

Given a Grothendieck topology above, the model structure of the localization can be described by hypercovers of this topology.
By this theorem, there should be a Grothendieck topology for $Ho(Sm_k)$ that gives the localisation $(sPSh^{\Delta}(Sm_S)_{\mathcal{U}Nis})_{\overline{\mathcal{H}(Nis)}}\cong sPsh(Sm_k)_{\mathcal{A_1},\overline{Nis}}$ of $sPsh^{\Delta}(Sm_k)$. The Grothendieck topology of the $\mathcal{U}$-local model topos $sPSh^{\Delta}(Sm_S)_{\mathcal{U}Nis}$ arises from the Nisnevich topology of $Sm_k$ as ordinary category. So this topology isn't the one that gives the final localization.

**How can one determine this Grothendieck topology hence find the fibrant objects of $sPre(C)_{\mathbb{A}_1,\overline{Nis}}$?**

Comment: "This localisation is equivalent to the localisation of the set of all bounded hypercovers.": only for hypercomplete sites.  This is false, for example, for the etale site.

Comment: Concerning the newly added question: what is the meaning of the expression "homotopy theory passes to"?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I have edited the question to be more specific

Comment: "are the fibrant objects and the A^1-homotopy classes the same": an A^1-homotopy class is by definition a collection of objects.  In what sense is a collection of objects is supposed to be "the same" as a fibrant object (i.e., a single object)?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I just mean if the A^1 homotopy class of the model topos the same as that of the motivic homotopy category. But anyway let me just ask if the fibrant objects are the same. Sorry for the misleading question. I have edited the question

Comment: No, the fibrant objects are not the same.  When you close Nis under homotopy base changes in sPre(C)_{A^1}, you get a much bigger class of morphisms.  Localizing with respect to this class produces a model topos, which has fewer fibrant objects than sPre(C)_{A^1,Nis}, which is not a model topos.  This is all explained in detail in the paper by Raptis and Strunk that I mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I have looked at that paper. But there is not too much about the model topos besides the formal properties. Is there a more concrete way to characterise the fibrant objects? Why is it interesting to consider this model topos?

Comment: This paper represents the state-of-the-art knowledge about this subject, I'm afraid.  It does contain an explicit description of fibrant objects, see Remark 3.11, which describes the Grothendieck topology that produces this model topos.  It's interesting to consider this model topos because its objects retain a lot of information about the motivic homotopy category (which contains the model topos as a reflective full subcategory).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97032/discussion-between-nicky-and-dmitri-pavlov).

Comment: To answer the question about how objects retain information: the motivic homotopy category sPre(C)_{A^1,Nis} canonically maps to the Raptis-Strunk model topos sPre(C)_{A^1,\overline{Nis}} via the localization functor provided by the left Bousfield localization.  The localization functor is essentially surjective.  The Raptis-Strunk model topos is fairly big, and so localizing an object from the motivic homotopy category extracts a substantial amount of information.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov For Remark 3.11, it gives the fibrant objects in the U-local model structure $sPsh^{\Delta}(Sm_S)_{U_{Nis}}$, how does it give the fibrant objects in $sPre(C)_{A^1, \overline{Nis}}$?

Comment: The motivic model topos is a proper full subcategory of the motivic homotopy category, so the localization functor loses some information.  Concerning Remark 3.11, elsewhere in the same paper they explain how localization at A^1 can be modeled by enriched presheaves (i.e., sPre^Δ) so that the resulting model category is Quillen equivalence to sPre_{A^1}.  So it doesn't make a difference whether to use sPre^Δ or sPre_{A^1}.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I understand there is a model structure on the enriched presheaves cat equivalent to the $A_1$ localisation on the presheaf cat and the other enriched model categories can be otained by the adjunction pair. Consider the unenriched ones $sPre(Sm_S)_{\mathbb{A}_1}\to sPsh(Sm_S)_{Sing-Nis} \to sPsh(Sm_S)_{\mathbb{A}_1,Nis}\to sPsh(Sm_S)_{sing-Nis,\tilde{Nis}}$  summarised in 5.3, $Sing-Nis,\tilde{Nis}$ topos is equivalent to $A_1,\tilde{Nis}$ topos, why is it considered as the localisation from Sing-Nis topos (equivalent to the $U$-local topos) instead of from $A_1$ topos?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Remark 3.11 gives the Grothendieck topology for the $U$-local topos equivalent to Sing-Nis topos, so the fibrant objects can be described by the Grothendieck topology, how this description gives the fibrant objects in the final localisation $sPsh^{\Delta}(Sm_S)_{UNis,\tilde{H(Nis)}}\cong sPsh(Sm_S)_{Sing-Nis,\tilde{Nis}}$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand all the notation here.  What exactly is the difference between sPsh(Sm_S)_Sing−Nis and sPsh(Sm_S)_{Sing−Nis,\bar Nis}?  It appears to me that elements of \bar Nis are already invertible in sPsh(Sm_S)_Sing−Nis, so there is no difference.

Comment: Conerning fibrant objects: you can transfer both local morphisms and local objects along Quillen equivalences.  In particular, the Grothendieck topology itself can be transported along the Quillen equivalence between the simplicially enriched and the A^1-localized presheaves.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov There is a diagram in summary 5.3 for the notations, I don't think Sing-Nis and Sing-Nis,\bar{Nis} are the same. It says that the Sing-Nis topos doesn't satisfy the same Nisnevich descent as the motivic homotopy category does. Then theorem 2.18 is applied to the set Nis to obtain another model topos Sing-Nis, \bar{Nis}.  The Grothendieck topology is given only for the U-local topos which can be transported to Sing-Nis topos. But I think the model topos of interest is Sing-Nis, \bar{Nis} which is equivalent to A_1,\bar{Nis}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are the fibrant objects of sPre(C)_Nis the same as sPre(C)_Nis?

Yes.  This follows from the characterization of fibrant objects
in a left Bousfield localization as fibrant objects in the original
model structure that are also local.

The closure of S under homotopy base changes does not change the class of local objects: S is contained in S-local weak equivalences and
the class of S-local weak equivalences of simplicial presheaves in any model topos
(such as sPre(C)_Nis) is closed under homotopy base changes (computed in simplicial presheaves before localization) because the localization (sheafification) functor
sPre(C)→sPre(C)_Nis is right exact, i.e., preserves finite homotopy limits.
Since S-local weak equivalences are the same, the S-local objects are also the same.

Comment: Do you mean that $hocolim _Imap(X^I,Y)\cong map(holim_I X^I, Y)$ for homotopy function complex $map(-,-)$?

Comment: @Nicky: No.  I added details to the answer.

Comment: But $sPre (C)_{Nis}$ is not a model topos.

Comment: @Nicky: sPre(C)_Nis is very much a model topos, by definition.  sPre(C)_{A^1} is not a model topos, but that was not in the original question.  A paper by Raptis and Strunk "Model topoi and motivic homotopy theory" is relevant.  In particular, they construct some model toposes that are related to the motivic homotopy category and also discuss to what extent the motivic homotopy category satisfies the properties of a model topos.

Comment: I was wrong. $sPre(C)_{Nis}$ is a model topos, but how about consider the localization of $sPre(C)_{A_1}$ at Nis?

Comment: @Nicky: This localization is not a topos.  What is the question being asked about sPre(C)_{A^1,Nis}?

Comment: Just to clarify what I mentioned above, sPre(C)_{A^1} (without the Nisnevich localization) is a model topos (since it can be presented as a the category of simplicial presheaves on the simplicial A^1-enrichment of C), whereas sPre(C)_{A^1,Nis) (with the Nisnevich localization) is not a model topos.